# datastax : Spark job fails : Removing BlockManager with no recent heart beats

Tags: jvm, apache-spark, datastax-enterprise

Im using datastax-4.6. I have created a cassandra table and stored 2crore records. Im trying to read the data using scala. The code works fine for few records but when i try to retrieve all 2crore records it displays me follwing error.

```
 **WARN BlockManagerMasterActor: Removing BlockManager BlockManagerId(1, 172.20.98.17, 34224, 0) with no recent heart beats: 140948ms exceeds 45000ms

15/05/15 19:34:06 ERROR ConnectionManager: Corresponding SendingConnection to ConnectionManagerId(C15759,34224) not found**
```

Any help?

Answer (score 3):

This problem is often tied to [GC pressure](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Heartbeat-exceeds-td3798.html)

#### Tuning your Timeouts

Increase the spark.storage.blockManagerHeartBeatMs so that Spark waits for the GC pause to end.

SPARK-734 recommends setting `-Dspark.worker.timeout=30000 -Dspark.akka.timeout=30000 -Dspark.storage.blockManagerHeartBeatMs=30000  -Dspark.akka.retry.wait=30000 -Dspark.akka.frameSize=10000`

#### Tuning your jobs for your JVM

**spark.cassandra.input.split.size** - will allow you to change the level of parallelization of your cassandra reads. Bigger split sizes mean that more data will have to reside in memory at the same time.

**spark.storage.memoryFraction and spark.shuffle.memoryFraction** - amount of the heap that will be occupied by RDDs (as opposed to shuffle memory and spark overhead). If you aren't doing any shuffles, you could increase this value. The databricks guys say to make this similar in size to the size of your oldgen.

**spark.executor.memory** - Obviously this depends on your hardware. Per DataBricks you can do up to 55gb. Make sure to leave enough RAM for C* and for your OS and OS page cache. Remember that long GC pauses happen on larger heaps.

**Out of curiosity**, are you frequently going to be extracting your entire C* table with Spark? What's the use case?

Comment: thanks . Im trying to do moving average calculation on  stock data  stored in cassandra.

Comment: Can i set this JVM tuning options in sparsh-env.sh file ?? Or, can u please guide me how can i use via command line ?

Comment: Yes in the spark env.sh please look at the ticket I reference SPARK-734